# Microsoft Office 2011 Mac: Reminders don't interact correctly with Spaces or Expose

Tags: mac, microsoft-office, osx-spaces, expose

I'm using Microsoft Office 2011 on Snow Leopard. I'm a heavy Spaces user. Whenever Microsoft Office Reminders pops up a reminder, it brings up the reminder in my current screen. However, if I do something else before dismissing the reminder pop-up, I can't easily find the pop-up again: Clicking on the icon in the dock does nothing and the pop-up vanishes when you use Expose. Left with no other choice, I simply end up clicking through each screen, moving windows around to hunt down the pop-up again.

Is there any easier way to locate that pop-up? Is there a way to get the pop-up to behave like a normal window?